# How retrieve Class that annotated by Jackson @JsonDeserialize?

Tags: java, json, jackson

My task is deserialize json object to enum. See example at the end of the page.

But I can't define which enum create in method `JsonEnumDeserializer.deserialize` (Drive or some other).

I want just annotate my enum `@JsonDeserialize(using = JsonEnumDeserializer.class)` and it should deserialize all annotated enum by way I described.

1) For this I tried extend `org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.EnumDeserializer` but it fails at runtime requiring no arg constructor or fails at compile time requiring override just parent constructor `EnumDeserializer(EnumResolver<?> res)`.
I tried dig into `EnumDeserializer` how it retrieve Enum Class but it did not give me any result.

2) Other solution add field "type" to json, but it's bad solution.

In method `JsonEnumDeserializer.deserialize` I would like retrieve Class that annotated by `@JsonDeserialize` (it will solve problem). Could somebody help me?

```
{
  "make":"Mazda",
  "model":"6",
  "drive":{
    "id":"FWD",
    "name":"Front wheel drive"
  }
}

public class Car {
    private String make;
    private String model;
    private Drive drive;

    /* setters and getters */
}

@JsonDeserialize(using = JsonEnumDeserializer.class)
public enum Drive {
    FWD, RWD, AWD
}

public class JsonEnumDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Enum> {
    @Override
    public Enum deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String enumName = jp.readValueAsTree().findValue("id").asText();
        return ??? /* Knowing enumName how can I figure out which enum Class return? Drive enum or other enum? I want write universal deserializer for all enum */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution I found is change Jackson to Gson. Gson can say instance of which Class is expected to be returned. Argument `Type type`.

```
public class GsonEnumDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Enum> {
    @Override
    public Enum deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {
        try {
            Class enumClass = Class.forName(type.getTypeName());
            String enumName = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("id").getAsString();
            return (Enum) enumClass.getMethod("valueOf", String.class).invoke(null, enumName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

/* usage */
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(Enum.class, new GsonEnumDeserializer())
    .create();
Car car = gson.fromJson(carJson, Car.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a custom `JsonDeserializer` at all in this case.

The `drive` field in `Car` is an enum, not an Object, so your json should be:

```
{
  "make":"Mazda",
  "model":"6",
  "drive":"FWD"
}
```

Either your json text or you're `Car` class is wrong.

Comment: But it should work so. Serialized enum should contain localized field in json - name. And I should deserialize this enum.

Comment: Did you consider using a wrapper object containing the enum and the localized field?

Comment: No. I write invisible mechanism that serialize and localize objects

Comment: Just return `Drive.valueOf(enumName)` then, but your localized string will be lost during deserialization.

Comment: It's main problem. I will have a lot of enums, not only Drive and for which enum should I invoke valueOf(enumName)? Jackson's class `EnumDeserializer` solves this problem somehow but I can't understand how  can I use it.
 ps minute ago I renamed `JsonDriveDeserializer` to `JsonEnumDeserializer` to disambiguate.

Comment: Localized string does not matter during deserialization.

Comment: I don't think you can implement such a generic enum deserializer, unless you're going to add more type information in your json representation.

Comment: I have learned docs, and I too think that Jackson does not provide required functionality, but Gson provides.
I About additional information in json I have written above, this solution does not fit

Comment: Welcome, it looks like Gson more flexible than Jackson.